# What is the meaning of saying that say something is "like laguna beach"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-meaning

I saw [this video](https://youtu.be/xFFs9UgOAlE?t=2324) on YouTube. Mark Zuckerberg said that "whenever that [a peak on a traffic graph on an LCD] happens, it's like laguna beach." What does that mean?

Comment: [Laguna Beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguna_Beach,_California) is a place.  I'm not familiar with any idiomatic use, but I suspect that Laguna Beach has frequent traffic jams, on days when the beach traffic is high.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The city of Laguna Beach is located just southeast of greater Los Angeles in Orange County—closer to the cities of Anaheim (home of Disneyland) and Irvine. Laguna Beach sits on the intersection of north–south U.S. Highway 1 (the famously scenic coastal highway) and east–west U.S. Highway 133, but its traffic situation is evidently often very bad.

Here is an excerpt from a [TripAdvisor review](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g32588-d344242-r408941788-Thai_Brothers-Laguna_Beach_California.html) of Thai Brothers, a restaurant in Laguna Beach:

> Very friendly staff, eat in or take out, either way worth dealing with the horrible Laguna Beach traffic and parking, we only live 5 miles from Laguna but it's always hard work getting there and parking.

Another annoyed (and more detailed) posting—this one on Blogspot (March 20, 2012)—is provocatively titled "[Laguna Streets: Why Laguna Beach Traffic Can Never Improve](https://lagunastreets.blogspot.com/2012/03/civic-groups-are-diversion.html)."

It would be misleading, however, to suggest that Laguna Beach is notorious throughout California for its bad traffic. I have never heard it singled out for criticism on this point where I live (in northern California) and my daughter (who lived in Los Angeles for several years) says that the worst of the famously bad traffic snarls in greater Los Angeles is "the 10" (Interstate Highway 10).

Nevertheless, a person visiting or passing through Laguna Beach by car might hit it at a bad time and find the experience memorably bad. And that may have happened to Mark Zuckerberg. My impression from the YouTube excerpt is that he was free-associating "Laguna Beach," not invoking a familiar idiom.